# How to edit a model with its relations with form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have a problem using a `form_for`-tag in rails.

I have the following models:

Holidays

```
   id      |   name
___________|_____________
   123     |   "asdf"
   345     |   "foo"
   757     |   "bar"
```

Holidates

```
   id      |   date
___________|_____________
   223     |   1998-03-11
   445     |   1999-06-21
   557     |   2009-09-20
```

Countries

```
   id      |   name      |   country_code
___________|_____________|________________
   667     |   "italia"  |   "it"
   987     |   "france"  |   "fr"
   999     |   "austria" |   "au"
```

R_Countries

```
   id      |   country_id|   holiday_id
___________|_____________|________________
   463     |   667       |   123
   574     |   987       |   345
   687     |   999       |   757
```

R_Holidates

```
   id      |   holidate_id|   holiday_id
___________|______________|________________
   142     |   123        |   223
   253     |   345        |   445
   362     |   757        |   557
```

I want to use one form to create a holiday, with a name, date and country, so this would be my _form:

```
<%= form_for(@holiday) do |f| %>
  <% if @holiday.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@holiday.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this timespan from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @holiday.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :holidate %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :holidate %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country_code %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :country_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :country_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But, for sure, when executing the script, I get this Error:

**NoMethodError in Holidays#edit
Showing C:/xampp/htdocs/fluxcapacitor/app/views/holidays/_form.html.erb where line #20 raised:
undefined method `holidate' for #**

---

EDIT:
Here is a design example, how it should look:
[image: Layout]

---

EDIT2:
I have populated my Database with my seeds-file, where I used a script like:

```
from = Date.civil(2000,1,1)                                                         
to = Date.civil(2000,12,31)                                                             
Holidays.between(from, to, :any ).each do |date|                                    
    lname = date[:name]
    ldate = date[:date]
    lregion = date[:regions]
    Holiday.find_or_create_by(name:  lname)             #Holiday is created
    Holidate.find_or_create_by(date: ldate)                                                                                  #creates a Holidate
    RHolidate.find_or_create_by(holidate_id: Holidate.find_by(date: ldate).id, holiday_id: Holiday.find_by(name: lname).id)  #this should create a relation between the holiday and it's date
    ####
    lregion.each do |x|
        Country.create(country_code: x, name: x)
        if  !(RCountry.exists?(country_id: Country.find_by(country_code: x).id, holiday_id: Holiday.find_by(name: lname).id))
            RCountry.create(country_id: Country.find_by(country_code: x).id, holiday_id: Holiday.find_by(name: lname).id)
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: what relation between `Holidays` and `Holidates`? you need add form for relation for @holiday. Please post model and controller instead table.

Comment: @Monk_Code : It's a many_to_many-relation. Isn't there a way, to create it, using a single form?

Comment: you need [fields_for()](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) in you form_for()

Comment: How do you mean this?
What does this do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure about you code, but your form can looks like(refine for you needs):

```
<%= form_for(@holiday) do |f| %>
  ........some code about errors here....


 <%= fields_for :holydate, @holyday.holydate do |holydate| %>
   <%= holydate.date_select :holidate  %>
  <% end %>

  ........some other code here....

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Or there is an alternative way using tags and calling them in the create/update methods:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'Date' %><br />
    <%= date_field_tag 'holidate' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'Countrycode' %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :country_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'Countryname' %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag 'country_name' %>
  </div>
```

Here is also the controller method:

```
  def create
    @holiday = Holiday.new(holiday_params)
    e=Date.civil(d[:year].to_i,d[:month].to_i,d[:day].to_i)
    holidate=Holidate.where(:date => e).first_or_create
    RHolidate.where(:holidate_id => holidate.id, :holiday_id => @holiday.id ).first_or_create
    country=Country.where(:name => params[country_name], :country_code => params[country_code] ).first_or_create
    RCountry.where(:country_id => country.id, :holiday_id => @holiday.id ).first_or_create
    respond_to do |format|
      if @holiday.save
        format.html { redirect_to @holiday, notice: 'Holiday was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @holiday }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This helped a lot, but I found an easier way, to create this.
I will edit your post, because yours is very right too!